# Enforce boundaries of key in an index

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

I am trying to have a function that takes an index as parameter where the key is limited to a key of T

```
function aliasSet<T>(values: {[x:keyof T]:string})
//compiler error: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'
```

Is there anyway to achieve that? Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index signature parameters can only be `number` or `string` (not even `number | string`)

You are looking for mapped types, specifically for the `Record` mapped type:

```
function aliasSet<T>(values: Record<keyof T, string>)
```

Ex:

```
declare function aliasSet<T>(values: Record<keyof T, string>) : void;
interface O {
    foo: number,
    bar?: boolean
}

aliasSet<O>({
    bar: "", // Record erases optionality, if you want all to be optional you can use Partial<Record<keyof T, string>>
    foo: ""
})
```

Comment: Great, that's it! I saw Record<K, T> in the documentation but was not quite sure how to use it. Thanks for that!